# Implement voting using REST

Tags: php, web-services, rest, web-applications

I'm working on my first web application and have this basic doubt.

I have a group of posts and I want to allow users to vote on them. I'm working with PHP so I have an `article.php` script with code that handle HTTP requests.

At the moment I implemented article creation which uses data sent through a POST HTTP request (using html form). The article id returned is the one I get from the DB storing articles.

Similarly, I handle GET requests and return an article based on the id sent as a parameter. If no parameter is defined, I return a list of all articles.

For the moment I haven't done any url rewrite so requests are of the form `article.php?id=xxx`

Now I want to implement votes, and this is where I'm facing a problem. According to REST, I should use POST on a specific resource (given that votes aren't idempotent) so I'd send a POST request to `/article/1234` with a body `"+1"` for a positive vote.

The question is, how do I map the above to my use case? Assuming url rewrite was made, what would that translate to? Doing a rewrite to `article.php?id=1234` wouldn't work because POST doesn't take parameters in the URI (AFAIK).

And also, how would I distinguish this action from any other? Should I also add some "action" parameter like `article.php?id=1234&action=vote`?

Comment: Doesn't the rewrite retain the POST body?

Comment: It does, but then how do I pass the data in the url (in this case the article id) into the POST body?

Comment: You just get the `id` from `$_GET['id']` and the body from `file_get_contents('php://input')` since it's not url encoded.

Comment: @enenen Whether or not Ajax is used is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Using GET for this would defeat REST purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as did not get the real idea of a REST-ful application. Retrieving the articles with GET and edit it with POST is fine, but you have to expand this to votes. REST-ful applications assume that one url identifies one resource. So, you have to think of votes as an own resource (that are related to articles).
So, your application should work like this

*GET article.php/id/1*: retrieve the article with id 1

*POST article.php/id/1*: alter the artcile with id 1

*GET article.php/id/1/votes*: retrieve the votes of the article with id 1

*POST article.php/id/1/votes*: alter the votes of article with id 1

Its completely fine to implement the latter one with adding one up-vote, as long as votes are implemented as a simple counter.
You may redefine this logic by giving the votes identity, e.g. if you want to add more attributes to a vote like the user who made the vote.

As you asked for the rewrite and if an application is able to get data from the url with a post-request: Yes, thats completely possible. A POST request to article?id=1 will have $_GET['id'] available.

The rewrite-part as shown above is completely optional. REST is not interested in the "niceliness" of a url as long as ONE url identifies ONE resource.

Hopefully this gave you an idea of how to continue

Comment: Aha! The fact I could use parameters in POST requests was the bit I was missing. I think part of the fault was the lack of clarity in using $_GET within a POST request. Thanks!